# How can I make a JUnit test wait?

Tags: java, junit, thread-safety

I have a JUnit test that I want to wait for a period of time synchronously. My JUnit test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testExipres(){
    SomeCacheObject sco = new SomeCacheObject();
    sco.putWithExipration("foo", 1000);
    // WAIT FOR 2 SECONDS
    assertNull(sco.getIfNotExipred("foo"));
}
```

I tried `Thread.currentThread().wait()`, but it throws an **IllegalMonitorStateException** (as expected).

Is there some trick to it or do I need a different monitor?

Comment: This answer provides an example utility method that will wait for a specified arbitrary amount of time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77401398/328275

Answer (score 130, accepted):

How about `Thread.sleep(2000);` ? :)

Comment: If you are using code analysis tools like sonarqube they will complain about `Thread.sleep` saying something like

_Using Thread.sleep in a test is just generally a bad idea. It creates brittle tests that can fail unpredictably depending on environment ("Passes on my machine!") or load. Don't rely on timing (use mocks) or use libraries such as Awaitility for asynchroneous testing._

Comment: This answer should be removed, and considered harmful. A much better answer below is https://stackoverflow.com/a/35163873/1229735

Comment: To avoid the "Thread.sleep should not be used in tests" sonar code smell, use the solution in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51650781/1167954

Comment: Thread.sleep() is not recommended by SonarQube. This answer does the job but it is misleading according to the coding standards.

Comment: This is a correct answer. OP never asked about SonarQube, so not seeing how that matters here.

Answer (score 120):

Thread.sleep() could work in most cases, but usually if you're waiting, you are actually waiting for a particular condition or state to occur.  Thread.sleep() does not guarantee that whatever you're waiting for has actually happened.

If you are waiting on a rest request for example maybe it usually return in 5 seconds, but if you set your sleep for 5 seconds the day your request comes back in 10 seconds your test is going to fail.

To remedy this JayWay has a great utility called [Awatility](https://github.com/jayway/awaitility) which is perfect for ensuring that a specific condition occurs before you move on.

It has a nice fluent api as well

```
await().until(() -> 
{
    return yourConditionIsMet();
});
```

https://github.com/jayway/awaitility

Comment: I couldn't get awaitability to compile in Android Studio.

Comment: Did you add this line to you gradle file:     compile 'org.awaitility:awaitility:3.0.0'       ?

Comment: no. you would add this in a test case where you want to wait for a particular condition

Comment: This is such a brilliant utility! Also there is a kotlin dsl.

Answer (score 40):

In case your static code analyzer (like SonarQube) complaints, but you can not think of another way, rather than sleep, you may try with a hack like:
`Awaitility.await().pollDelay(Durations.ONE_SECOND).until(() -> true);`
It's conceptually incorrect, but it is the same as `Thread.sleep(1000)`.

The best way, of course, is to pass a Callable, with your appropriate condition, rather than `true`, which I have.

https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility

Comment: @Jitendra: Note that Awaitility used to have the `Duration` class, but since version 4 they renamed it to `Durations`.

Comment: One caveat, if you want the poll delay to be 10 seconds or more, be sure to increase the timeout to more than 10 seconds since that is the default timeout and awaitility will complain that timeout is less than the poll delay.

Answer (score 29):

You can use java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit library which internally uses Thread.sleep. The syntax should look like this :

```
@Test
public void testExipres(){
    SomeCacheObject sco = new SomeCacheObject();
    sco.putWithExipration("foo", 1000);

    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);

    assertNull(sco.getIfNotExipred("foo"));
}
```

This library provides more clear interpretation for time unit. You can use 'HOURS'/'MINUTES'/'SECONDS'.

Comment: If I start a worker thread from within a test, will the `sleep()` affects the worker thread?

Comment: Sonar doesn't complain about `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);` but the underlying problem is the same: you're blocking the thread and it might behave differently on your test server ("but worked on my machine" (TM))

Comment: This code does not compile. `TimeUnit.sleep` (like `Thread.sleep`) declares that it `throws InterruptedException`, but `testExipres` does not catch it, nor does it declare that it `throws InterruptedException`.

Answer (score 22):

If it is an absolute must to generate delay in a test `CountDownLatch` is a simple solution. In your test class declare:

```
private final CountDownLatch waiter = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

and in the test where needed:

```
waiter.await(1000 * 1000, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); // 1ms
```

Maybe unnecessary to say but keeping in mind that you should keep wait times small and not cumulate waits to too many places.

Comment: IntelliJ unfortunately complains because the result of `await` is ignored.

Comment: @Druckles are you making an assignment like `var result = waiter.await(..`? In that case do not make it. If not doing it then the warning is weird. There could be some "checkstyle" rule that require always an assignment but hardly is.

Comment: @pirho Can I invoke `waiter.await()` multiple times within a test?

Comment: @linuxNoob Why not. For me even Junit5 parallel test run seems to work as should for the same class level static `CountDownLatch` when I use it several times in two separate tests.

Comment: @Druckles the following trick has worked for me to avoid the warning `assertThat(waiter.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS), equalTo(false))`

Answer (score 12):

[**Mockito**](https://site.mockito.org/) (which is already provided via transitive dependencies for Spring Boot projects)  has a couple of ways to wait for asynchronous events, respectively conditions to happen.

A simple pattern which currently works very well for us is:

```java
// ARRANGE – instantiate Mocks, setup test conditions

// ACT – the action to test, followed by:
Mockito.verify(myMockOrSpy, timeout(5000).atLeastOnce()).delayedStuff();
// further execution paused until `delayedStuff()` is called – or fails after timeout

// ASSERT – assertThat(...)
```

Two slightly more complex yet more sophisticated are described in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211024124855/https://fernandocejas.com/blog/engineering/2014-04-08-unit-testing-asynchronous-methods-with-mockito/) by [@fernando-cejas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/760596/fernando-cejas)

---

My urgent advice regarding the current top answers given here: you want your tests to

1. finish as fast as possible
2. have consistent results, independent of the test environment (non-"flaky")

... so just don't be silly by using `Thread.sleep()` in your test code.

Instead, have your production code use dependency injection (or, a little "dirtier", expose some mockable/spyable methods) then use Mockito, [Awaitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938538#30471990), [ConcurrentUnit](https://github.com/jhalterman/concurrentunit) or others to ensure asynchronous preconditions are met before assertions happen.

Comment: OMG, how I lived before that for 10 years

Answer (score 7):

You could also use the `CountDownLatch` object like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025366/wait-until-boolean-value-changes-it-state).

Answer (score 4):

There is a general problem: it's hard to mock time. Also, it's really bad practice to place long running/waiting code in a unit test.

So, for making a scheduling API testable, I used an interface with a real and a mock implementation like this:

```java
public interface Clock {
    
    public long getCurrentMillis();
    
    public void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException;
    
}

public static class SystemClock implements Clock {

    @Override
    public long getCurrentMillis() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    }
    
}

public static class MockClock implements Clock {

    private final AtomicLong currentTime = new AtomicLong(0);
    

    public MockClock() {
        this(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    
    public MockClock(long currentTime) {
        this.currentTime.set(currentTime);
    }
    

    @Override
    public long getCurrentMillis() {
        return currentTime.addAndGet(5);
    }

    @Override
    public void sleep(long millis) {
        currentTime.addAndGet(millis);
    }
    
}
```

With this, you could imitate time in your test:

```java
@Test
public void testExpiration() {
    MockClock clock = new MockClock();
    SomeCacheObject sco = new SomeCacheObject();
    sco.putWithExpiration("foo", 1000);
    clock.sleep(2000) // wait for 2 seconds
    assertNull(sco.getIfNotExpired("foo"));
}
```

An advanced multi-threading mock for `Clock` is much more complex, of course, but you can make it with `ThreadLocal` references and a good time synchronization strategy, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Using Thread.sleep in a test is not a good practice. It creates brittle tests that can fail unpredictably depending on environment ("Passes on my machine!") or load. Don’t rely on timing (use mocks) or use libraries such as Awaitility for asynchroneous testing.

`Dependency : testImplementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:3.0.0'`

```
await().pollInterval(Duration.FIVE_SECONDS).atLeast(Duration.FIVE_SECONDS).atMost(Duration.FIVE_SECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> {
      // your assertion
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the Awaitility library.

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
  <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
  <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Unit test utility method to wait for some specified amount of time:

```
 public void waitFor(Duration duration) {
    final Instant startTime = Instant.now();
    Awaitility
      .await()
      .atMost(duration.plus(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
      .with()
      .pollInterval(duration)
      .until(() -> {
        Duration elapsed = Duration.between(Instant.now(), startTime);
        return elapsed.abs().compareTo(duration) >= 0;
      });
  }
```

Example usage based on OP:

```
@Test
public void testExipres(){
    SomeCacheObject sco = new SomeCacheObject();
    sco.putWithExipration("foo", 1000);
    Duration pt2s = java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(2);
    waitFor(pt2s);
    assertNull(sco.getIfNotExipred("foo"));
}
```