# Why synchronized can not synchronize thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have set the value of the flag, but the result is not 'add' and 'sub' alternates. Why? When I look at the result, it has executed twice the 'sub' method. But when the 'sub' method ended, the value of the flag will be set 'false'. But as a result, it printed "subxxxxx" twice continuously.

```
class Resource {
    private boolean flag = true;
    private int num = 0;

// At here I have declared an add()
    public synchronized void add() throws InterruptedException {
        if (this.flag == false) {
            super.wait();
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
        this.num++;
        System.out.println("addition:"+Thread.currentThread().getName() + this.num);
        this.flag = false;
        super.notifyAll();
    }

// At here I have declared an sub()
    public synchronized void sub() throws InterruptedException {
        if (this.flag == true) {
            super.wait();
        }
        Thread.sleep(200);
        this.num--;
        System.out.println("subtraction:"+Thread.currentThread().getName() + this.num);
        this.flag = true;
        super.notifyAll();
    }
}

/*
* I will test it with multiple threads. For example:
*new Thread(ad, "add").start();
*new Thread(ad, "add").start();
*new Thread(sub, "sub").start();
*new Thread(sub, "sub").start();
*When threads start. it will execute alternately. For example:
Thread add:0
Thread sub:-1
Thread add:0
Thread sub:-1
Thread add:0
Thread sub:-1
Thread add:0
Thread sub:-1
But the result is like this:
Thread add:0
Thread sub:-1
Thread sub:-2
Thread add:-1
Thread sub:-3
Thread sub:-4
Why?Why?Why?
*/
        new Thread(ad, "add").start();
        new Thread(ad, "add").start();
        new Thread(sub, "sub").start();
        new Thread(sub, "sub").start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not figure it out. Please help me -0-

Comment: This code will not compile as is.  Please edit and ensure it compiles.

Comment: We can't explain what this is doing without seeing *all* of the code.

Comment: The code is too long. He won't allow me to upload it all

Comment: I have used multiple threads. But the result is not call add() and sub() alternately.

Comment: Why do you call `super.wait()`? That does the same thing as `wait()` or `this.wait()`, but is quite confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to assume that when your `wait()` call finishes, that the `flag` has changed to what you wanted to have before you called `wait()`. There is no such guarantee, especially since you have more than two threads involved. You should check if you need to continue waiting. Also see [Wait until boolean value changes it state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19025366/14955)

But in general, these constructs are too low-level to use (unless you want to learn the nitty-gritty) and you should look at the concurreny utils package for easier higher-level constructs (like Queues, Latches, Conditions).

Comment: I have a question. I assume that the value of the flag is false now. I think the thread about 'sub()' must wait. I see what's your mean is when I change the value of 'flag' it will occur one sub() is running another sub() will be waked. But the method is modified by keyword 'synchronized'. Will that happen?

Comment: Now, I only want to implement this case with add() and sub() executing alternately.  I know that there are some errors in my codes. But I do not know where the error is.

Comment: If you want them to alternate, you have to make sure that you check that flag before resuming. Replace `if (flag == false) { wait();}` with `while (flag == false) { wait();}`

Comment: I don't know the difference between them. The method is modified by 'synchronized'. So, it will only one thread call sub() one time. Why? But The result was exactly what I expected

Comment: When you `wait()` you give up the lock and another thread can enter the synchronized block.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.